# dialog --buildlist option, how to use it?

Tags: scripting, dialog

I've been reading up on the many uses of dialog to create interactive shell scripts, but I'm stumped on how to use the --buildlist option. Read the man pages, searched google, searched stackoverflow, even read through some old articles of Linux Journal from 1994, to no avail.

Can some give me a clear example of how to use it properly?

Lets imagine a directory with 5 files which  you'd want to select from, to copy to another directory. Can someone give a working example?

Thankyou!

Comment: You talk about a bunch of stuff you supposedly did, but present none of it here. How are we expected to even know what you are trying to do?

Comment: The source code has working samples, e.g., [this](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/samples/buildlist) and [this](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/samples/buildlist2).  Requests for tutorials are off-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
dialog --buildlist "Select a directory" 20 50 5 \
  f1 "Directory One" off \
  f2 "Directory Two" on \
  f3 "Directory Three" on
```

This will display something like

```
     ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
     │ Select a directory                             │
     │ ┌─────────────────────┐ ┌────^(-)─────────────┐│
     │ │Directory One        │ │Directory Two        ││
     │ │                     │ │Directory Three      ││
     │ │                     │ │                     ││
     │ │                     │ │                     ││
     │ │                     │ │                     ││
     │ └─────────────────────┘ └─────────────100%────┘│
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     │                                                │
     ├────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
     │           <OK>          <Cancel>               │
     └────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The box is 50 characters wide and 20 rows tall; each column displays 5 items. `off`/`on` determines if the item starts in the left or right column, respectively.

The controls:

- `^` selects the left column
- `$` selects the right column
- Move up and down the selected column with the arrow keys
- Move the selected item to the other column with the space bar
- Toggle between OK and Cancel with the tab key. If you use the `--visit-items` option, the tab key lets you cycle through the lists as well as the buttons.
- Hit enter to select OK or cancel.

If you select OK, the tags (`f1`, `f2`, etc) associated with each item in the right column is printed to standard error.

Comment: Don't you mean that the output is sent to standard error? According to the manpage and my experience, the output of the selected listitem is sent to standard error.